# Generar un reporte en PDF en PHP Y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Buenas noches realizo un reporte en PDF con PHP y MYSQL de lo que contiene mi tabla de mi BD son:

*(tabla principal)"trabajador" con los atributos id_control, nombre, ap_parterno, ap_materno, NSS, CURP, RFC y con las llaves foraneas id_puesto, id_area, idctg_turno, idctg_empresa

*Tabla "area" con los atributos id_area, descripcion_area

*Tabla "ctg_turno"  con los atributos idctg_turno, descripcion

*Tabla "empresa" con los atributos idctg_empresa, descripcion_empresa.

Lo que pretendo que haga mi reporte en PDF es que tome las descripciones de los ID de mis llaves foraneas es decir, si el id_area es igual a 1 que muestre la descripcion

```html
<?php

require_once('../lib/pdf/mpdf.php');
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','admon');
$query = ("SELECT t.id_control, t.nombre, t.ap_paterno, t.ap_materno, t.NSS, t.CURP, t.RFC, p.descripcion_puesto, a.descripcion_area, tu.descripcion, e.descripcion_empresa FROM trabajador t INNER JOIN puesto p ON t.id_puesto = p.id_puesto INNER JOIN area a ON t.id_area = a.id_area INNER JOIN ctg_turno tu ON t.idctg_turno = tu.idctg_turno INNER JOIN empresa e ON t.idctg_empresa = e.idctg_empresa");
$prepare = $conn->prepare($query);
$prepare->execute();
$resulSet = $prepare->get_result();
while($trabajador[] = $resulSet->fetch_array());
$resulSet->close();
$prepare->close();
$conn->close();






$html = '<header class="clearfix">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
      </div>
      <h1>Reporte de Trabajadores Registrados</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
    <th>No. de Control</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
   <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
   <th>Apellido Materno</th>
   <th>NSS</th>
   <th>CURP</th>
   <th>RFC</th>
   <th>Puesto</th>
   <th>Área</th>
   <th>Turno</th>
   <th>Empresa</th>
 
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
  
  foreach ($trabajador as $trabajador){
  $html.='<tr>
  
              <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['id_control'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['nombre'].'</td>
     <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['ap_paterno'].'</td>
     <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['ap_materno'].'</td>
     <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['NSS'].'</td>
     <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['CURP'].'</td>
     <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['RFC'].'</td>
     <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['id_puesto'].'</td>
     <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['id_area'].'</td>
     <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['idctg_turno'].'</td>
     <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['idctg_empresa'].'</td>
                    
                    </tr>';
  
   
   
   
  }
  
          $html.='
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div id="notices">
        <div>Aviso:</div>
        <div class="notice">Este documento es propiedad de Concorde Group S.A de C.V.</div>
      </div>
    </main>';

$mpdf = new mPDF('c','A4');
$css = file_get_contents('css/style.css');
$mpdf->writeHTML($css,1);
$mpdf->writeHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('reporte.pdf','I');








?>
```

id_empresa es igual a TIP (que contiene el id_area=1). Lo intento hacer con un JOIN.

Consulta

```
SELECT 
  t.id_control, 
  t.nombre, 
  t.ap_paterno, 
  t.ap_materno, 
  t.NSS, 
  t.CURP, 
  t.RFC, 
  p.descripcion_puesto, 
  a.descripcion_area, 
  tu.descripcion, 
  e.descripcion_empresa 
FROM trabajador t 
INNER JOIN puesto p 
  ON t.id_puesto = p.id_puesto 
INNER JOIN area a 
  ON t.id_area = a.id_area 
INNER JOIN ctg_turno tu 
  ON t.idctg_turno = tu.idctg_turno 
INNER JOIN empresa e 
  ON t.idctg_empresa = e.idctg_empresa
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema exactamente? Qué error te da?

Comment: Solo me muestra los ID y lo que quiero que me muestre son las descripciones que contiene esas llaves foráneas de sus respectivas tablas.

Comment: La consulta parece que esta bien, pero cuando construyes la tabla muestras los id's, ejemplo `$trabajador['id_puesto']` cuando deberías hacer referencia a la columna `$trabajador['descripcion_puesto']` lo mismo con el resto.

Comment: Perfecto, tienes mucha razón. Gracias / Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado en lugar de utilizar un while podrías utilizar `fetch_all` para recuperar todas las filas en un Array    http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la consulta estas pidiendo a MYSQL que te devuelve las siguientes columnas en el SELECT

```
SELECT 
  t.id_control, 
  t.nombre, 
  t.ap_paterno, 
  t.ap_materno, 
  t.NSS, 
  t.CURP, 
  t.RFC, 
  p.descripcion_puesto, 
  a.descripcion_area, 
  tu.descripcion, 
  e.descripcion_empresa 
--- resto de consulta ---
```

Pero luego cuando recorres los resultados de la consulta tratas de mostrar otros diferentes:

```
$html.='<tr>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['id_control'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['nombre'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['ap_paterno'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['ap_materno'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['NSS'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['CURP'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['RFC'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['id_puesto'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['id_area'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['idctg_turno'].'</td>
                    <td class="qty">'.$trabajador['idctg_empresa'].'</td>

                    </tr>';
```

Debes utilizar las columnas que recuperase en la consulta, por ejemplo en lugar de `$trabajador['id_puesto']` debería ser `$trabajador['descripcion_puesto']`.